# Evaluation of function: derivative,integral, absolute continuity

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, integration, derivatives

I'm in trouble with this exercise tough I thought it was not that difficult at the begininng, now I definitely changed my mind.
So I hope someone could help me to solve it. Give the function:
$f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined as
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right), \qquad x\neq 0\\
     0  ,               \qquad\qquad\qquad \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$
I have to show that this function is derivable, but that $f'$ is not integrable and deduce that $f$ is not absolutely continuous.
I started proving that the functions is continuous on $[0,1]$. Then I calculate the derivative:
$$
f'(x)=
\begin{cases} 2x \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+\frac{2}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \qquad x\neq 0\\
     0          \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\,       \qquad x=0
\end{cases}
$$ 
so it exist in every point and I can guess that the $f$ is derivable but also that $f'$ is not continuous since the limit as $x\rightarrow 0$ doesn't exist and $f$ isn't $C^1$.
Is it right?
Now to prove that is not integrable. I can't understand how to do it, I mean $f'$ is not continuous but has a finite number of points of non-continuity so I'd say that the integral exist but could take infinite value.
Now if I calculate the integral and I got that it has a infinite value.
How can I desume the non absolute continuity of $f$?
And also is my trial correct up to now? Especially the compute of the integral.

Comment: Integral does not exist at discontinuity points.

Comment: Ok but there's just one point, so I can say that the integral exist  almost everywhere?
I think that if a function is continuous except from a finite number of point is possible to calculate is integral but maybe it is infinite,and that's the case.I think.